# WinRar file window and extraction destination window don't respond when extracting the file

Tags: windows, winrar

WinRar file window and extraction destination window don't respond when extracting the file. I don't think it's a bug or anything. The extraction process doesn't stop. All window responds when after the extraction and copying are done. This is so annoying.

Is there any way to stop it from happening?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I undertand your question clearly. I think this is simple behavior of program winrar the window will not respond when you are extracting file and it will come back again when it done.

You can press Ctrl + Tab untill you see your windows to check the mini window as well if you need to see it.